# how to get the response object from a single query in cloud firestore using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query in cloud firestore and trying to extract document id and there is one other value also called cc i am able to extract the information but using .forEach and but i wanted to ask is there another way to do it here is my query

```
const recipient = await db
    .collection("Active")
    .where("office", "==", "d")
    .where("template", "==", "dt")
    .where("attachment.Name.value", "==", "xyz")
    .get();

const id = [];
  const cc = [];
  recipient.forEach((doc) => {
    id.push(doc.id);
    cc.push(doc.data().cc);
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
  });
```

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code? So what line doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i am getting the desired output but i don't want to use  forEach and map for one document only. is there any way to solve this problem without forEach and map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one document in the query result,

```html
const recipient = await db
    .collection("Active")
    .where("office", "==", "d")
    .where("template", "==", "dt")
    .where("attachment.Name.value", "==", "xyz")
    .get();

const id = [];
const cc = [];

id.push(recipient.docs[0].id);
cc.push(recipient.docs[0].data().cc);
```